# Read a text file and split parts of it

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of ip addresses that I need to split.

Ex: ip-10-254-11-4.ec2.internal

I can split a single one by using a.split(".") but what if I have a list of these?

Here

```
with open("aws_instances_dnsname.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split("."):
            print(word)
```

I am not getting the expected results but getting something like 
ip-10-254-11-4
ec2
internal

Comment: Is there a list in a single line? What is the separator between them? What is unexpected about your result, it has split the parts of the string around the .

Comment: Nope, it is actually like a text file. The result I got was something like this:
ip-10-232-8-185
ec2
internal

ip-10-232-121-44
ec2
internal

ip-10-232-121-119
ec2
internal

The seperator is a "."

Comment: So does each IP address begin with ip-?

Comment: Yup it does, I just need the ip-x.x.x.x only. Thanks

Comment: nvm, got it. with open("aws_instances_dnsname.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        l = line.split(".")
        print (l[0])

Comment: But that would only print the first IP address not all of them on the line

Comment: No it prints everything, atleast it did when I tested.

Comment: `'ip-10-254-11-4.ec2.internal'.partition('.')[0]` will produce `'ip-10-254-11-4'` which I think is what you are looking for.

Comment: @dawg Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to separate the different IP addresses then get the IP part of it:

```
with open("aws_instances_dnsname.txt", "r") as f:
  for line in f:
    for ip in line.split("ip-"):
      print(ip.split(".")[0])
```